# Thickened Slab vs separate pad below slab for interior load bearing post?

Tags: concrete, load

I am in East Tennessee, building a new construction home that has a point in the middle of the building that is load bearing.  The cause is a beam across the ceiling that rests on solid blocking (posts) at each end.  One end is at the exterior wall of the house so will carry down to the perimeter footings.  My question is about the other end, which is at the center of the house, resting on the basement floor which will be a concrete slab.

Is it best to:
(a) pour a separate pad/footer (36"x36") at this interior location then let the slab sit directly on that footer or...
(b) just thicken the slab at that point?

[image]

Comment: option B would be most common.  There should be local building codes that dictate what method you should use.

Comment: (c) have your engineer design the footing and reinforcement to suit the load and conditions. And consider putting some steel in your basement slab which is drawn as non-reenforced in both sketches - it costs little extra for the large benefit.

Comment: that does not sound DIY...

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I checked with the local code inspector and he said that either is acceptable to him, so I believe that I will do (b).  By the way, there will be steel in the slab too... I left that detail out of the sketch.